# I need to make a complex HTML Table but I just don't understand how

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the HTML code of the table

```html
<table border="1px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">Diese Spalte geht über sechs Reihen</td>
      <td colspan="4">Diese Spalte geht über die Breite von vier Spalten</td>
      <td rowspan="6">Diese Spalte geht über sechs Reihen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Diese Spalte geht über zwei Reihen</td>
      <td colspan="2">Diese Spalte geht über die Breite von zwei Spalten</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Diese Spalte geht über zwei Reihen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eine Spalte</td>
      <td>Eine Spalte</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Diese Spalte geht über zwei Reihen</td>
      <td>Eine Spalte</td>
      <td>Eine Spalte</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Diese Spalte geht über zwei Reihen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Diese Spalte geht über die Breite von zwei Spalten</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">Diese Spalte geht über die Breite von vier Spalten</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

my only problem now is the CSS aspect
[The table I am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDZtX.png)

Answer (score 2):

1. The red text color can be applied with: `table { color: red; }`
2. the outside table border is applied with: `table { border-style: outset; }`
3. The border for each cells using: `td { border-style: outset }`

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

table {
  border: 3px outset grey;
  color: red;
}

td {
  border: 1px inset black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6">Diese Spalte geht über 6 Reihen</td>
    <td colspan="4">Diese Spalte geht über die Breite von vier Spalten</td>
    <td rowspan="6">Diese Spalte geht über 6 Reihen</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Diese Spalte geht über zwei Reihen</td>
    <td colspan="2">Diese Spalte geht über die Breite von zwei Spalten</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Diese Spalte geht über zwei Reihen</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eine Spalte</td>
    <td>Eine Spalte</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Diese Spalte geht über zwei Reihen</td>
    <td>Eine Spalte</td>
    <td>Eine Spalte</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Diese Spalte geht über zwei Reihen</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Diese Spalte geht über die Breite von zwei Spalten</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">Diese Spalte geht über die Breite von vier Spalten</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: TY you are a true saviour